# $ is not a function on jQuery .hover() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to have an "opacity change on hover" function (and it should work without CSS :hover):

```
$(document).ready($(function() {
    $( ".ba-gallery-grid.css-style-7 .ba-image img" ).hover(function() {
        $(this).css('opacity', '.3');
        $(this).css('opacity', '1');
    });
}));
```

With this HTML:

```
<div class="ba-gallery-grid css-style-7">
    <div class="ba-gallery-items category-0 category-1">
        <div class="ba-image"></div>
        <img data-original="***" alt="" src="***">
        <div class="ba-caption">
            <div class="ba-caption-content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But all I have is an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Could anyone please help me to figure out what I have done wrong? Here is the page with full example http://lilianpix.ru/photos.

Comment: Have you included jQuery on page, I don't think so

Comment: You haven't included jquery.js in your page, or if you have, then the path to it is incorrect.

Comment: Of course it's included: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js

Comment: Why not use CSS `:hover`. `.ba-gallery-grid.css-style-7 .ba-image img { opacity: 1} .ba-gallery-grid.css-style-7 .ba-image img:hover {opacity: .3}`

Comment: @Tushar please visit this page now. This is what I was looking for. Some kind of inverted function of CSS-hovering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the said page you have included `jquery-noconflict.js`, which calls [jQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) that will reset the value of `$`. You can still use `jQuery` to refer to jquery so

Also note that, to hover you need to pass 2 callbacks, one to set the opacity when mouse enters and when mouse leaves

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".ba-gallery-grid.css-style-7 .ba-image img").hover(function () {
        $(this).css('opacity', '.3');
    }, function () {
        $(this).css('opacity', '1');
    });
});
```

Comment: mybe he hasn't linked the jQuery javascript.